# list内の要素並び替え

Tags: python

下記のリストがあるとします

```
list_1 = "abcabcabcabc"
list_2 = ["b", "a", "a", "c", "b"]
```

list_2の要素をlist_1の要素順に並べるにはどのように
行えばよろしいでしょうか？

下記のように出力したいです。

```
# 目的の出力
output = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "c"]
```

お分かりの方がいましたら教えて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list_1の値が、list_2にも存在すれば、outputに追加するという形でやってみました。

```py
list_1 = "abcabcabcabc"
list_2 = ["b", "a", "a", "c", "b"]

output = []

for num in list_1:
    if num in list_2:
        list_2.remove(num)
        output.append(num)
        
print(output)
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
いろんなロジックが知れてかなり学習になります。
ありがとうございまいました。

Comment: どちらかの回答で解決した場合は、チェックマークをつけるとこの質問は、解決済みになるので、解決済みであれば、チェックマークをつけておいてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
先ほど対応いたしました。
以後気を付けます。

Answer (score 0):

```py
list_1 = "abcabcabcabc"
list_2 = ["b", "a", "a", "c", "b"]

p = {i: 0 for i in {*list_1}}
order = [(i:=list_1.index(x, p[x])+1) and p.update({x: i}) or i for x in list_2]
output = [v for _, v in sorted(zip(order, list_2), key=lambda x: x[0])]

print(output)

#
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
頑張ってこのロジックを理解します。